# insert random integers into table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to update SQL statement to add a randomly generate combination of letters and number and I want it to be 10 digits only

```
 UPDATE `transaction` SET NumberofUser=NumberofUser+1 , referencenumber= randnum
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE `transaction` SET NumberofUser=NumberofUser+1 , 
       referencenumber= left(md5(999999999*rand()),10)
```